# dynamic import of images react

Tags: reactjs, image, oop, ecmascript-6

I am trying to dynamically render images from a local folder within my project

The object structure looks like this

```
{
        id: 2,
        text: 'How would you describe your level of influence in management of the farm?',
        type: 'cardChoice',
        choices: [
          {
            id: 1,
            text: 'I am the primary decision maker',
            questionId: 'Hm?',
            value: 'I am the primary decision maker',
            image: '1.jpg',
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            text: 'I hent',
            questionId: 'Hrm?',
            value: 'I',
            image: '2.jpg',
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            text: 'I arm',
            questionId: '?',
            value: 'Irm',
            image: '3.jpg',
          },
        ],
      },
```

In my component I select the folder that contains the images `const baseUrl = '../../assets/images/CNA'`

After that, in my return I try to render the images

```
<img src={`${baseUrl}'${questionChoice.image}'`} alt={questionChoice.text} />
```

The page renders, but my image isn't loading and it's showing my `alt` instead

Heres my full component

```
const CardChoiceQuestions = ({ cardChoiceArray, currentAnswer, updateCurrent, submitAnswer }) => {
  const { id, value } = currentAnswer
  const baseUrl = '../../assets/images/CNA'
  return (
    <ButtonContainer>
      {cardChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => {
        return (
          <Button
            active={questionChoice.id === id}
            type="button"
            key={questionChoice.id}
            onClick={() => {
              const answer = { id: questionChoice.id, value: questionChoice.value }
              updateCurrent(answer)
              submitAnswer()
            }}
          >
            <p>{questionChoice.text}</p>
            <img src={`${baseUrl}${questionChoice.image}`} alt={questionChoice.text} />
          </Button>
        )
      })}
    </ButtonContainer>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this here in case someone comes across this...

```
<img src={require(`../../assets/images/CNA/${questionChoice.image}`)} alt={questionChoice.text} />
```

Not sure why I can't use `${baseUrl}` but this works for now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my laptop in front of me but a few things I noticed. Do you need a slash "/" after your base url? Also, the string concatenation should be completed in one set of brackets after the $ sign. Not sure if that's the issue try a few console.log(string path) amd verify it is going where you think it is. It looks like the path may be wrong. You may be better off conditional rendering images as opposed to building a dynamic url but either way it should render on change.

Comment: Ok I know it's been a few days but as I was talking to a friend of mine today I realized something. It is possible that react will not render the image tag on a url change only because it did change the url portion so maybe the image won't always rerender? Just as a side note a better approach would be to create your own image component with the url as a prop. If so I'd think it would render on prop change and get the new pic. So if you are still having issues give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src={`${baseUrl}/${questionChoice.image}`} alt={questionChoice.text} />
```

use like this

Comment: Does not work, I think @Paul W is right, my path may be wrong